# Mouseover preview for bar instead of datapoint in StackedColumn chart

Tags: javascript, dom-events, maps, mschart

I have a StackedColumn chart which I'd like to add a mouseover preview.  Currently I'm looping through the points of a series to add the the functionality to do this.

This makes each series in the column will do a mouseover/mouseout.  I'd like it to do a single mouseover/mouseout for the column.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not a popular question.

I stumbled across the CustomizeMapAreas event.  In there I looped through the `e.MapAreaItems` and adjusted the size of the areas so that there was just one area for the entire column.  Then I removed the areas I didn't need anymore.  It's probably not the most efficient way to do it, but here it is...

```
protected void FixStackedColumnAreas(object sender, CustomizeMapAreasEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<float, MapArea> newAreas = new Dictionary<float, MapArea>();

    //loop through all areas and collect the Min and Max Y values for each X 
    foreach (MapArea area in e.MapAreaItems)
    {
        if (!newAreas.ContainsKey(area.Coordinates[0]))
        {
            newAreas.Add(area.Coordinates[0], area);
        }
        else
        {
            //get the lowest and highest Y for this X column area
            newAreas[area.Coordinates[0]].Coordinates[1] = Math.Min(newAreas[area.Coordinates[0]].Coordinates[1], area.Coordinates[1]);
            newAreas[area.Coordinates[0]].Coordinates[3] = Math.Max(newAreas[area.Coordinates[0]].Coordinates[3], area.Coordinates[3]);
        }
    }

    //clear out existing areas
    e.MapAreaItems.Clear();

    //put in our new areas that define the whole column area instead of the individual pieces of the column
    foreach (MapArea area in newAreas.Values)
    {
        e.MapAreaItems.Add(area);
    }
}
```